# Volume differences between intercom and outside communications

Tags: radio-communications, radio

While flying I can hear my instructor in my headset talking no problem, but when they (and me) are speaking with ground/tower the volume in my headset is much lower. Is there anyway to increase the volume of the communications outside of the airplane?

Sorry, but different airplanes I fly in (172's) have different radios so I can't definitively quote the radio models and since it is happening in different airplanes its not tied to one specific plane or radio.

Based on the post
[Do pilots have separate volume knobs on the radio panel?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49577/do-pilots-have-separate-volume-knobs-on-the-radio-panel) I think yesterday we had a Garmin GNS430, the others look similar also.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation! Radios have a volume control - your instructor should be able to show you. Why do you think the question you linked does not answer your question?

Comment: Just curious, why haven't you asked your instructor?

Comment: I did ask my instructor but they were uncertain of the reason why the difference in volume.

Comment: Don't forget you are paying them to teach you basic things like that!  My expectation would be a response along the lines of "good question, I haven't flow the GNS430 enough where I have needed to do this, but let's go look it up."  Or, if cost conscious, "do you want me to look it up before our next lesson, or do you want to read through the manual youself?"

Comment: @Alfie I'm happy to reopen this, but without specifics you'll get no better answer than the linked question. If you took a picture of the radio stack on one or more of the 172s you regularly fly I'm sure we can point out the relevant knobs to twiddle next time you're flying

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate all the input. I'll figure it out somehow. If I do I'll post here.